# ProgressDialog RuntimeException

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am displaying a ProgressDialog in an AsyncTask, as follows.

```
public class DataComm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
...
ProgressDialog pd = null;
...
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(activity, activity.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_please) + "\u2026", "", true);
    ...
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);        
    ...
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

The PD is declared in the class which implements AsyncTask. I initialize it in onPreExecute, using the context of the activity which creates the and attempt to call pd.dismiss() at the end of doInbackground. This is called from multiple activities, in some it works, but in others I get a RuntimeException "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread". 
In the failure case, I know that the activity which I used to create the PD is still alive, so I don't understand what thread has died.

The problematic call is from a class which is derived from a base class used to update a list for a class derived from ArrayAdapter.  The AsyncTask is called when the ArrayAdapter needs to fill the list of options. Does this happen on some thread other than the UI main thread. I still don't see why it should die before the onPostExecute is called.

Comment: RuntimeExcption usual means another Exception please post your Logcat

Comment: @ItzikSamara the cause of the RuntimeException is "sending message to  a Handler on a dead thread."

Comment: create the PD outside of the AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Async Task doInbackground method runs on background in separate thread other than main thread. Please check it may be because of some reason this is dying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first create Constructor for AsyncTask **DataComm** ,then initialize your `ProgressDialog` in constructor like this:

```
public class DataComm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
...
ProgressDialog pd;
...

public void DataComm(Context mContext)
{
  pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

}
protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.pd.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_please) + "\u2026");
    this.pd.show();
    ...
}
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);        
    ...
    if (pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class DataComm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
       pd = ProgressDialog.show(activity, activity.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_please) + "\u2026", "", true);
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         pd.setProgress(progress[0]);
     }
    protected void onPostExecute() {
      super.onPostExecute(result);        
      ...
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run(){
           if (pd.isShowing()) {
               pd.dismiss();
            }
          }
       });            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter support seems to have been the problem. Updating the list from the UpdateMap override seems to take place on a separate thread. When I put the call inside a runOnUiThread there was no more dead thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataComm dc = new DataComm(itemFetcher, activity, pd);
            dc.execute("main", "product_search","search_prefix", newFilter);
        }
    });
```